# I don't know how this function works. Can anyone explain this to me?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const arr =[];

function bar(...a) {
    arr.push(a);
}

['a','b'].forEach(bar);

console.log(arr)
// the response is [['a','0',['a','b']],['b',1,[circular object Array]]]
```

I tested in sandboxes, jsfiddle and others and I got ['a','b'] at the end instead of [circular object Array] in few

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the function `bar` pushes an array of its arguments to `arr`. Example:

```js
const arr = [];

function bar(...a) {
  arr.push(a);
}

bar(1, 2, 3);
bar("a", "b", "c");

console.log(arr);
```

`forEach` will call `bar` for each element of `["a", "b"]` with the following parameters:

1. The value of the element,
2. The index of the element and
3. The array.

The array is always a reference to `["a", "b"]`. Let's call it `ab`.

For the first element, the value is `"a"` and the index is `0`. For the second one, the value is `"b"` and the index is `1`. So `arr` contains:

```js
[
  ["a", 0, ab], // First element
  ["b", 1, ab]  // Second element
]
```

```js
const arr = [];

function bar(...a) {
  arr.push(a);
}

["a", "b"].forEach(bar);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) takes a function and invokes it once for each item in the array, passing in the current element as the first argument, the index as the second, and the array itself as the third.

So these lines are all roughly equivalent:

```js
['a','b'].forEach((item, index, array) => arr.push([item, index, array]));
['a','b'].forEach((item, index, array) => bar(item, index, array));
['a','b'].forEach((...args) => bar(...args));
['a','b'].forEach(bar);
```

Your `bar` function pushes the arguments into the new array, so this is effectively:

```js
function bar(item, index, array) {
    arr.push([item, index, array]);
}
```

So after the first iteration, arr is:

```js
[['a', 0, ['a', 'b']]]
```

And after the second iteration:

```js
[['a', 0, ['a', 'b']], ['b', 1, ['a', 'b']]]
```

As for the "circular object" console output, I could see that maybe occurring if you called `arr.forEach(bar)`, because that would result in a reference to `arr` being pushed into an entry within `arr`, creating a circular reference, where arr contains a reference to arr which contains a reference to arr which contains a referenece to arr...